# y<C-G> not yanking commit SHA in fugitive?

Tags: key-bindings, git, plugin-fugitive

I'm having some trouble getting the <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>C-G</kbd> command in normal mode to yank the current commit SHA. Currently it only yanks the file name.

From `:h fugitive`:

> ["x]y<C-G>     Yank the commit SHA and path to the current object.

I've tried running `:Gedit` after which <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>C-G</kbd> yanks `:0:file-name.ext`.

I'm confused. Am I using this keyboard shortcut correctly, or is there a bug?

It exhibits the same behavior in both gui mode and text mode.

I'm using the most recent version of [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) (as of 2015-04-02).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that was the vim binary I was using wasn't compiled with `+xterm_clipboard`.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you should be on a fugitive-revision for that to work. (:h fugitive-revision).

Comment: I eventually figured out I needed to open a specific revision from the quickfix list. I nmapped a key command to `:Glog<CR>:cwindow<CR>` to help with this.